# How to fix 'error: syntax error at or near "end"' error from pg dependency in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I am extremely new to postgres (just started up about 30 minutes to an hour ago) and I am already stuck on an error (`(node:33564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: syntax error at or near "end"`).

Currently, I am making a giveaway system for a Discord bot, and I would like the giveaways to still persist even if the bot restarts, which led me to turn to postgres for a database.

This is the code I attempted to use to add a giveaway to the database.

```js
client.query(`INSERT INTO discord.giveaways (content, end, channel, winners, message)
    VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`, [content, end, channel, winners, message]);
```

This code returns the following error: `(node:33564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: syntax error at or near "end"` upon being called.

The value of each variables are the following:

```
[
  'hello',
  1550518888972,
  '539577989197856776',
  1,
  '547140492039684097'
]
```

The columns of the discord.giveaways schema:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column name `end` is an reserved keyword (see [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)).

You can either rename your column name or escape it with `"`.

Try:

```sql
INSERT INTO discord.giveaways (content, "end", channel, winners, message) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);
```